# onClickListeners with bindview and newview (best practise)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursor

I have a button and I register listener , code like this

```
    Button remove=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button_remove_item);
    remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

my question is where should I put this code ?

-just on newView

-just on bindView

-in both

My assumption is that for every listitem the method newView it must be called at least ones and bindView should never be called before newView is called at least ones for that item, is this correct ?

```
public View newView(final Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
```

Comment: i personally do it just in `bindView` and haven't faced any problems as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should put in the onCreate() method that been called when the programm starts.

Comment: no it can't be done like that ! , as I said there are 3 possibilities but I do not know what is the right one

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure, but may be this can drop you a clue.

In newView(), you would create the ViewHolder for the row and associate it with setTag(). 
In bindView(), you would retrieve the ViewHolder via getTag()

go through this link

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/